# ng-view not displaying template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-routing, ng-view

I'm following a tutorial from Pluralsight about Angular basics, and one of the topics that it covers is about routing using `ngRoute`.

So I'm having troubles with that specific topic because I'm trying to make an app that manages routes, and I don't have any clue how to make it work since it doesn't show any errors.

Here's the `index.html` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularPlayground">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular playground</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
        <!-- Angular initalization -->
        <script src="app-module.js"></script>
        <script src="app-router.js"></script>
        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="app/main/main-ctrl.js"></script>
        <script src="app/faces/faces-ctrl.js"></script>
        <script src="app/location/location-ctrl.js"></script>
        <!-- Services -->
        <script src="app/faces/faces-service.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to the Angular playground</h1>
        <h4>Select what you want to see.</h4>

        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the routes file.

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('angularPlayground')
        .config(function($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html'
                })
                .when('/faces/:username', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/faces/user.html',
                    controller: 'FacesController'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        });
})();
```

And here's the `main.html` file.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Experiments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Faces API</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
</ul>
```

I did check if the path of the `main.html` file is correct, and it should be, because when I enter its URL in the browser, it loads without any problem.

By the way, [here's the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Wlny3QbaVdHlrrvjeXp?p=preview), if you need it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `location-ctrl.js` file is redefining your `angularPlayground` module. Fixed here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/JFa4cI1aGl1pJS7zNHUB?p=preview

Comment: This is why I like using a one-module-per-file approach and combining all the module dependencies into the main app module.

Comment: @Phil Now it makes sense, thank you very much. But, can you explain that `one-module-per-file` approach a little further?

Comment: Sure but keep in mind this approach is meant for bower style loading; using NPM / `require()` would be different... Each JS file defines a module (`angular.module('specific.module.name', ['dependencies', 'go', 'here'])`) and any services, controllers, directives, etc. This way, the order that the files are loaded doesn't typically matter and you don't accidentally blow away any already defined modules. See [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) for an example